# Blurry lazy image loading by IntersectionObserver

Tags: angular, angular-directive, intersection-observer

I implement a **directive** for lazy load images like below that is works well:

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appLazyLoad]"
})
export class LazyLoadDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @HostBinding("attr.src") srcAttr = null;
  @Input() src: string;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canLazyLoad() ? this.lazyLoadImage() : this.loadImage();
  }

  private canLazyLoad() {
    return window && "IntersectionObserver" in window;
  }

  private lazyLoadImage() {
    const obs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      entries.forEach(({ isIntersecting }) => {
        if (isIntersecting) {
          this.loadImage();
          obs.unobserve(this.el.nativeElement);
        }
      });
    });
    obs.observe(this.el.nativeElement);
  }

  private loadImage() {
    this.srcAttr = this.src;
  }
}
```

usage example:

```
<img [src]="imageUrl" appLazyLoad />
```

now I want that the photos are **blurred first** and **then become clear**

Comment: https://lazy-load-image-blur.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add a style that blur by default then after its loaded, add style to clear the blur:
I make example for you in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/lazy-load-image-blur?file=src/app/app.component.scss)

```
.image {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20rem; /* layout hack */
  background: #fff center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(3px); /* blur the lowres image */
}
.image.is-loaded {
  filter: none; /* remove the blur on fullres image */
  transition: filter 1s;
}
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[appLazyLoad]"
})
export class LazyLoadDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    @HostBinding("attr.src") srcAttr = null;
    @Input() src: string;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer2,private  el: ElementRef) {
        renderer.addClass(el.nativeElement, 'image');//added
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.canLazyLoad() ? this.lazyLoadImage() : this.loadImage();
    }

    private canLazyLoad() {
        return window && "IntersectionObserver" in window;
    }

    private lazyLoadImage() {
        const obs = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
            entries.forEach(({ isIntersecting }) => {
                if (isIntersecting) {
                    this.loadImage();
                    obs.unobserve(this.el.nativeElement);
                }
            });
        });
        obs.observe(this.el.nativeElement);
    }
    
    private loadImage() {
        this.srcAttr = this.src;
        this.renderer.addClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'is-loaded'); //added
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, I need a blur of the original image